# How to add the values of selective cells of a row in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

Suppose I want to add the values of cell A4, D4, E4, G4 & show the sum in I4.
Similarly  I want to add the values of cell A5, D5, E5, G5 & show the sum in I5. I am very new in writing formulas but I have tried the following:

1. =SUM(A4, D4, E4, G4) ==> Error
2. A4 + D4 + E4 + G4 & pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter ==> This only copies the value of I4 to all I* cells.

......A......B......C......D......E......F......G......H......I
1
2
3
4....20...................20......20............20...........80

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data (a screenshot) so we can look at what is happening.

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose I have provided data. Can you please help

Comment: I see @cigmonkey has already answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

In I4 just write =(A4+D4+E4+G4)

Then click the cell and drag the lower right-hand corner down to I5

[image: example]

Comment: I would use 'SUM' instead of several plus signs "=SUM(A4:G4) will do exactly the same. I wonder if the problem Ajit has is due to the separator, he used a comma, in some regions you need to use a semi-colon.

Comment: True, you're right about the SUM function, I guess I was just thinking that in an actual file you may have values in B4, C4, etc. that you may not want to add.

Answer (score 0):

I used the auto-Sum icon on cell I4, then clicked in turn on A4, dragged over D4 and E4, and finally clicked on G4. That creates effectively the formula
=SUM(A4,D4:E4,G4)
(of course, typing the abovve formula would have the same result)

In order to create a table with different data in those cells, simply highlight (drag down) the I cells you wish, and hit Ctrl+D ("Fill Down")

[click for picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjmEz.png)